# How to use Goutte to submit a form and get final URI?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, web-crawler, goutte

The intent is to populate a `form[id=thisAwesomeRemoteForm][action=#]` on a remote website. There is only one field (`input[name=awesomeField]`) to populate and then, the form needs to be submitted. As a final requirement, the user needs to be redirected from my website to this remote website as if it has submitted the form on the remote website.

Long story short, I need the user to be able to click my link, make PHP do the job and get redirected to this remote website as if it has filled and submitted the form on the remote website. I have to not make the user fill the remote form by himself.

The code so far is:

```
use Goutte\Client;
// ...
public function gotoAction($data)
{
    $client = new Client();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', self::MY_URL);

    $form = $crawler->filter('form[id=thisAwesomeRemoteForm]')->form();

    $form->setValues(array('awesomeField' => $data));
    $crawler = $client->submit($form);

    return $this->redirect($form->getUri());
}
```

So far, I am redirected to the very first URL where the `form` is and not where the `form` should lead to. The field is populated with the right data though.

Is my code correct to achieve my purpose (and therefore, it's the remote website that may use JavaScript to send the form or whatever) or am I missing something fairly obvious?

Comment: Where does this form redirect? Do you control that? Is the request persistent between the `Goutte` request and the redirection. Does the redirection shows an empty form or the form is already submitted?

Comment: Hi @A.L! No I have no control over the form on the remote website. The form leads to another page on the remote server. What do you mean by `persistent request`? I don't think the form is submitted though.

Comment: By *persistent request* I meant that since Goutte and your user are two distinct visitors from the point of view of the remote server, I don't know how you can get the result of the submitted form and display it to the user.

Comment: is the form action url the same page? like a post on the same page ? i have never seen using the last ->redirect, just something like this 

`$crawler = $client->submit($form, array('stuff'));`
`echo $crawler->html();`

Comment: What kind of redirect are we talking about here? A `Location` header, a `<meta>` tag, a JavaScript snippet?

Comment: Thanks @all for commenting and replying. Unfortunately, my company decided to go with cURL instead of parsing the document with \Goutte. This question is therefore now irrelevant to my problem which has been solved. I'll leave it online for general knowledge though.

Comment: That's OK @D4V1D - we encourage posters and other editors to improve questions long after they have been answered. So, if you wouldn't mind answering my question about the redirect, it will give others something concrete to respond to should they wish to submit a new answer.

Comment: Hi @halfer. Of course I'd answer your question. My goal here was to be able to remotely fill the form and get it sent. It would then redirect the front-end user running the \Goutte script to the remote website as it has filled the form himself. So I'd guess a kinda `Location` header redirect.

Comment: (I know but SO doesn't allow more than two or three notifiers per comment).

Comment: OK, cool. So if the question is about a form being processed in a POST op, and then responding with a `Location` to cause the browser to follow immediately with a GET request, Goutte will handle that automatically (as will cURL).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76680/discussion-between-d4v1d-and-halfer).

Comment: (Sure! This question needs to be answered `:)`!)

Answer (score 1):

Goutte is by and large an adapter for Guzzle onto the `Symfony\Browserkit` API.  Based on a cursory analysis of the source code of `Goutte\Client` the `effectiveUrl()` is not used or carried over.  This would mean that if a redirect occurred you would not be "picking it up".

You can perform the same functions easily enough using the base components (Guzzle, DomCrawler) using the following code snippet:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'debug' => true, // only to troubleshoot
);

// Obtain the html page with the form
$request = $client->createRequest('GET', $url);
$response = $client->send($request);
// or $response = $client->get($url);

// create crawler and obtain the form.
$crawler = new Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler(null, $response->getEffectiveUrl());
$crawler->addContent(
    $response->getBody()->__toString(),
    $response->getHeader('Content-Type')
);

$form = $crawler->form('form_identifier');
$form->setValues($data_array);

//form submission
$request = $client->createRequest(
    $form->getMethod(),
    $form->getUrl(),
    [
        'body' => $form->getPhpValues(),
]);

$response = $client->send($request);
```

Comment: Maybe I've missed something in the question, but Guzzle uses cURL by default, which by default is set to respond automatically to up to five redirect requests. See `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` and `CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS` in the [options list](https://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).